# DonationsFragment issues (trying to replace spinner with edittext)

Tags: java, android

I am building an activity on a mobile app that would accept donations.  I am using the [DonationsFragment](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/donations) as a guide.  I am attempting to replace the Spinner used in the above example with an EditText so that the donor can type in a value to donate.

The following is my source code:

```
public class DonateFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_DEBUG = "debug";

public static final String ARG_GOOGLE_ENABLED = "googleEnabled";
public static final String ARG_GOOGLE_PUBKEY = "googlePubkey";
public static final String ARG_GOOGLE_CATALOG = "googleCatalog";
public static final String ARG_GOOGLE_CATALOG_VALUES = "googleCatalogValues";

private static final String TAG = "Donations Library";

// http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html
private static final String[] CATALOG_DEBUG = new String[]{"android.test.purchased",
        "android.test.canceled", "android.test.refunded", "android.test.item_unavailable"};

private EditText mGoogleEditText;
private Spinner mGoogleSpinner;

// Google Play helper object
private IabHelper mHelper;

protected boolean mDebug = false;

protected boolean mGoogleEnabled = false;
protected String mGooglePubkey = "";
protected String[] mGoogleCatalog = new String[]{};
protected String[] mGoogleCatalogValues = new String[]{};

/**
 * Instantiate DonationsFragment.
 *
 * @param debug               You can use BuildConfig.DEBUG to propagate the debug flag from your app to the Donations library
 * @param googleEnabled       Enabled Google Play donations
 * @param googlePubkey        Your Google Play public key
 * @param googleCatalog       Possible item names that can be purchased from Google Play
 * @param googleCatalogValues Values for the names
 * @return DonationsFragment
 */
public static DonateFragment newInstance(boolean debug, boolean googleEnabled, String googlePubkey, String[] googleCatalog,
                                            String[] googleCatalogValues) {
    DonateFragment donateFragment = new DonateFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putBoolean(ARG_DEBUG, debug);

    args.putBoolean(ARG_GOOGLE_ENABLED, googleEnabled);
    args.putString(ARG_GOOGLE_PUBKEY, googlePubkey);
    args.putStringArray(ARG_GOOGLE_CATALOG, googleCatalog);
    args.putStringArray(ARG_GOOGLE_CATALOG_VALUES, googleCatalogValues);

    donateFragment.setArguments(args);
    return donateFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDebug = getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_DEBUG);

    mGoogleEnabled = getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_GOOGLE_ENABLED);
    mGooglePubkey = getArguments().getString(ARG_GOOGLE_PUBKEY);
    mGoogleCatalog = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_GOOGLE_CATALOG);
    mGoogleCatalogValues = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_GOOGLE_CATALOG_VALUES);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.donatefraggoogle, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    /* Google */
    if (mGoogleEnabled) {
        // inflate google view into stub
        ViewStub googleViewStub = (ViewStub) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vwsGoogle);
        googleViewStub.inflate();

        // choose donation amount
        mGoogleEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtDonate);

        Button btGoogle = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.donations__google_android_market_donate_button);
        btGoogle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                donateGoogleOnClick(v);
            }
        });

        // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
        if (mDebug)
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating IAB helper.");
        mHelper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), mGooglePubkey);

        // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(mDebug);

        // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
        // will be called once setup completes.
        if (mDebug)
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (mDebug)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    openDialog(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert, R.string.donations__google_android_market_not_supported_title,
                            getString(R.string.donations__google_android_market_not_supported));
                    return;
                }

                // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
                if (mHelper == null) return;
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Open dialog
 */
void openDialog(int icon, int title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    dialog.setIcon(icon);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.donations__button_close,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
    );
    dialog.show();
}

/**
 * Donate button executes donations based on selection in spinner
 */
public void donateGoogleOnClick(View view) {
    String strDonation;
    strDonation = mGoogleEditText.getText().toString();
    if (mDebug)
        Log.d(TAG, "selected item in spinner: " + strDonation);

    if (mDebug) {
        // when debugging, choose android.test.x item
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(),
                strDonation, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP,
                0, mPurchaseFinishedListener, null);
    } else {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(),
                strDonation, IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP,
                0, mPurchaseFinishedListener, null);
    }
}

// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        if (mDebug)
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            if (mDebug)
                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

            // directly consume in-app purchase, so that people can donate multiple times
            mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);

            // show thanks openDialog
            openDialog(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, R.string.donations__thanks_dialog_title,
                    getString(R.string.donations__thanks_dialog));
        }
    }
};

// Called when consumption is complete
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        if (mDebug)
            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase + ", result: " + result);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            if (mDebug)
                Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");
        }
        if (mDebug)
            Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
    }
};

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (mDebug)
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
    if (mHelper == null) return;

    // Pass on the fragment result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        if (mDebug)
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}
}
```

When I click on the Donate button as I was testing it on my phone, it crashes and I get the following messages in LogCat:

```
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707): Process: com.danielburgnerjr.flipulatorfree, PID: 7707
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.danielburgnerjr.flipulatorfree/com.danielburgnerjr.flipulatorfree.DonateActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at com.danielburgnerjr.flipulatorfree.DonateFragment.onActivityCreated(DonateFragment.java:105)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1177)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5461)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
09-09 13:37:09.626: E/AndroidRuntime(7707):     ... 11 more
```

Is there something I have overlooked?

Comment: Is, by any chance, `R.id.txtDonate` declared as `TextView` in xml layout?

Comment: R.id.txtDonate is not declared as TextView in xml layout.

Comment: Can you post your xml layout pls?

Comment: See https://github.com/dburgnerjr/FlipulatorFree/blob/master/res/layout/donatefraggoogle.xml for the xml layout file in question.

Comment: hoomi I was one step ahead of you.

Comment: I found the issue. Do not use `getActivity().findViewById()` in `onActivityCreated`. Try using `getView().findViewById()` in `onViewCreated()`

Comment: You probably have another TextView in your activity layout with the same id as your EditText

Comment: Only now I've noticed the methods, shouldn't view-related stuff be in `onCreateView`, so you can use the view you inflate right away? Either that or use `getView()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for your comments.  I was able to correct the original issue only to have another issue pop up.  I moved this line to onCreateView():

```
 mGoogleEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtDonate);
```

and rewrote onCreateView() to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // choose donation amount
    View viewV = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.donatefraggoogle, container, false);
    mGoogleEditText = (EditText) viewV.findViewById(R.id.edtDonate);
    return viewV;
}
```

I did notice that txtDonate was listed as a TextView (in activity_donate.xml) and an EditText (in donatefraggoogle.xml).  I renamed the EditText txtDonate to edtDonate.

As to the other issue that popped up, I did notice that the viewStub to handle donations through Google Play Store was being displayed twice.